# How do I stop MSVC from telling me about the code it generates?

Tags: visual-c++, verbosity

My software performs some generation and compilation of C code under the hood.
I control this with Python’s Setuptools, which calls a C compiler of its own choice – on Windows this defaults to MSVC.
Now when compiling, MSVC emits messages like:

```
{{filename}}
Creating library C:\{{path}}
Generating code
Finished generating code
```

(The reason for this has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1778503/2127008).)
For my users, this is obstructive and confusing (since my software also generates code).
Therefore **I wish to disable these messages** via a compiler option, environment variable, or similar, i.e., in a way that can be controlled in my setting.

What I tried so far or what doesn’t work:

- I could not find anything useful in [the list of compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically) using keywords like *message, verbos*, status, generat*,* etc.
- Internet searches only return instructions (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1211841/2127008)) on how to click this or command-line options for other executables (that are not listed for MSVC).
- Setuptools’ `verbose` argument is already set to `False`, but I do not think that the solution lies within Setuptools, as this also happens when calling MSVC manually.

Comment: `cl some commands > nul:` perhaps?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I do not think I can wrap something around the compiler command with Setuptools. Also, this would suppress all output (except errors, perhaps), wouldn’t it?

Comment: Write your own wrapper that would launch `cl` with [redirected standard streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx), and filter its output as you see fit. Configure your build tool to launch your wrapper as the compiler. Maybe even just a `.bat` file that launches `cl` and pipes its output through `grep` or similar.

Comment: That sounds like it should be posted as an answer. (Apart from that it seems like a nightmare in terms of required effort, portability, and maintainability to me.)